# May one chemically castrate animals

Tags: halacha, animals, medicine, noachide-laws, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

According to Halacha, Jews are not supposed to castrate animals, and many poskim say this is a noahide law as well.

My question is whether this prohibition on castration of animals is just a prohibition on physical castration, or is chemical castration of animals also prohibited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Shulchan Aruch** ([EH 5:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.5.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) **permits chemical castration of female animals** but not of males

> **A person who gives a cup of root drink to** a person or **any living thing
> in order to render him impotent**, this is forbidden. But, he (the giver
> of the drink) is not lashed. However, **for a woman it is permitted to
> drink this root drink in order that she become impotent so she cannot
> give birth.**

At the time, a potion was the way to chemically castrate, today there are more modern methods (e.g., zeutering, see [here](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/a-halachic-analysis-of-spayneuter-by-scott-sears-jd) for details and a halachic analysis). Permitted methods for Jews would also be permitted for non-Jews.

Finally, I note there are workarounds available (see e.g., [here](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/6709/insights-from-the-institute-pet/#:%7E:text=The%20Gemara%20quotes%20an%20opinion,to%20castrate%20his%20own%20animal.)) based on the Rema in [5:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.5.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Answer (score 1):

פסקי תוספות בכורות פ"ט

> אסור לסרס אפילו על ידי שתיית סם

Piskei Tosafot Bechorot

> One may not castrate even through drinking a potion

Comment: Do later authorities rule this way?